# GROUP BY and JOIN in HIVE

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

How can I do something like this in HIVE:

Table1:

```
ID  Name        Friends
1   Tom         5
```

Table2:

```
ID  Name        DOB
1   Jerry       10/10/1999
1   Kate        Null
1   Peter       02/11/1983
1   Robert      Null
1   Mitchell    09/09/2000
```

What I want to do is:

For each ID in table 1, find num of not null DOB and then divide by Friends

I wrote a query as:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Friends, COUNT(s.DOB)/ t. Friends from Table1 t join Table2 s on (t.ID = s.ID) GROUP BY t.ID
```

When I do this, I get the error as FRIENDS is not part of the GROUP BY Key

The answer I am expecting is: 3/5

Comment: You need answer the question: which friends are you going to use in the calculation when you have multiple same ids? All? Any? Avg? Sum?

Comment: If id is the primary key in table one, you can add the friends to the group by.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the FRIENDS to your GROUP BY section:

```
 SELECT t.ID, t.FRIENDS, COUNT(s.DOB)/ t. FRIENDS 
 from Table1 t 
 join Table2 s      
 on (t.ID = s.ID) 
 GROUP BY t.ID. t.FRIENDS
```

I prefer to write this kind of query like this:

```
 SELECT t.ID, case when t.FIREND>0 then Cnt / t.FRIENDS ELSE 0 END 
 FROM Table t1 
 JOIN (Select ID, Count(*) AS Cnt  from Table 1 GROUP BY Id)  t2
 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have declare id,friends in table 1 as integer and id in table2 as integer, then below query will get you intended output

```
select a.name, concat(cast(b.cnt as string),'/',cast(a.friends as string)) 
from table1 a 
join 
    (select id, count(DOB) as cnt from table2 where DOB is not null group by id) b 
on (a.id = b.id)
```